# Why does msdb..sp_send_dbmail allow bad email addresses?

Tags: sql-server, email

Why does msdb..sp_send_dbmail allow bad email addresses?  It throws error "14624 - recipients cannot be empty" if you provide empty emails but if I enter an email for the recipients param: 'we12354wer234' it returns "Mail queued", No Error.

Running my test query @:
SSMS 2014 on local machine | connected-to | Sql Server 2005 on remote box

Thanks in advance for any information, advice or answers.

Answer (score 1):

How is it supposed to know that that is a bad email address? For all it knows it's a local address and doesn't need a domain name

Comment: As I suspect that's the obvious issue, however I just started using it today, and after several hours searching the net, reading articles and documentation, I've learned that it does practically everything you would ever want in sending out emails.  It's unfortunate MS did not build in bad email address intelligence.